# Selecting Entities with multiple relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following entities:

Vehicles

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CurrentOdometer { get; set; }
    ....
    public VehicleModel VehicleModel { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PerformedService> PerformedServices { get; set; }
}
```

VehicleModel

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ....
    public ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ServiceInterval> ServiceIntervals { get; set; }
}
```

ServiceIntervals

```
 public class ServiceInterval
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ....
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Kilometer Interval")]
    public int KmInterval { get; set; }

    public VehicleModel VehicleModel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ServiceSheet> ServiceSheets { get; set; }

}
```

ServiceSheets

```
[Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    .....
    public ServiceInterval ServiceInterval { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ServiceSheetQuestions> ServiceSheetQuestions { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PerformedService> PerformedServices { get; set; }

}
```

PerformedServices

```
 public class PerformedService
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vehicle Serviced")]
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Service Comments")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public ServiceSheet ServiceSheet { get; set; }
    public WeeklyService WeeklyService { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VehicleAction> VehicleActions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VehicleIssue> VehicleIssues { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ServiceSheetAnswer> ServiceSheetAnswers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WeeklyServiceAnswer> WeeklyServiceAnswers { get; set; }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is, I need the next Service Sheet from a Vehicle Model where there are no Performed Services from the Vehicle and the Service Interval is > then the Vehicle CurrentOdometer.

Im trying with this query:

```
 var teste = vehicle.VehicleModel.ServiceIntervals.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KmInterval > vehicle.CurrentOdometer && x.ServiceSheets.Where(b => b.PerformedServices.Intersect(vehicle.PerformedServices).Any()) == null);
 ServiceSheet serviceSheets = vehicle.VehicleModel.ServiceIntervals.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KmInterval > vehicle.CurrentOdometer && x.ServiceSheets.Where(b => !b.PerformedServices.Intersect(vehicle.PerformedServices).Any()) == null).ServiceSheets.Where(x => !x.PerformedServices.Intersect(vehicle.PerformedServices).Any()).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I'm not having success.

Comment: What does your lack of success look like? What is your result?

Comment: @agfc its returning null

Comment: Maybe you don't have any records that fit the criteria can you provide the data you are expecting to see and the other data it relates to.

Comment: With dummy data, the vehicle has a vehicle model with 2 service intervals(10k and 20k).
Each service interval has a service sheet. The 10k service sheet is already done, marked as a perform service, but the vehicle odometer is at 9k. I'm trying to get the next service sheet(20k)

Answer (score 0):

I really like the ability to query a database with LINQ queries, I think it's convenient, very readable, and fast as long as you monitor the queries that EF sends to your DB server.

In your case, though, the query is complex, and the probability that people will have difficulties getting the intent of the LINQ query is pretty high, in my opinion.

This is a very valid situation to *fall back* to plain old SQL. Good news is that [Entity Framework supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) and still takes care of binding the results to your domain classes. The result will be much easier to understand - especially with so many `JOIN`s - and you know EF won't create a monster query on its own.